# How to convert C# types to IronRuby types and vice versa?

Tags: c#, ironruby

For example:

ruby code (just for test):

```
def process_initial_array (ar)
     ar.join(" ")
end
```

c# code:
Here I create List of strings and pass it to the IronRuby

```
List<string> source_values = new List<string>();
```

it fills;

```
label2.Text=IronRuby.CSharp.BasicInteraction.calculator(source_values);


namespace IronRuby.CSharp
{
    public class BasicInteraction
    {internal static string calculator(List<string> source_values)
        {
            var rubyEngine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
            var scope = rubyEngine.ExecuteFile("math_logic.rb");
            string result = rubyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(scope, "process_initial_array", source_values);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

It evokes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly

Additional information: Unable to convert implicitly "IronRuby.Builtins.MutableString" to "string". There is explicit conversion.
```

OK, I found IronRuby string method to_clr_string in related questions, so the question is where I can find documentation about same methods for other types?

Answer (score 1):

After a brief look on the IronRuby [source code](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/Ruby/Libraries/Initializers.Generated.cs) I could only find `to_clr_string` and `to_clr_type` (to convert to `System.Type`) that seem to be relevant to your question. Thus, I *assume* those are the only conversion methods you need to convert between built-in ruby types and CLR types. Other types *should* be the same types as their CLR counterparts.

Note that there're also other methods to convert from ruby *strings* to other primitive types like `int` (`to_i`) and `double` (`to_f`).

In your example, you could explicitly convert the result to `string`:

```
var result = (string)rubyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(
  scope, "process_initial_array", source_values);
```

This way, you don't have to call `to_clr_string` on the Ruby side.